# Python cannot find local .PYD file with a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, module

I have written a DLL module in C++ and would like to use it in Python. I have already managed to have a 32-bit version working, but I need a 64-bit one now. I have changed the build script that creates the dll file (and renames it to .pyd), but now Python can't seem to find it. The current situation looks like this:

I have a call.py and a testing.pyd in the same directory. From this folder I call the "python call.py" command. The call.py has only one line

```
import testing
```

If the testing.pyd has been compiled as a 32 bit, the 64-bit Python says quite obviously

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing testing: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

If the testing.pyd has been compiled as a 64 bit, the 64-bit Python says

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I'd like to say that the .pyd files are named exactly the same. If I use 32-bit Python, the 32-bit compiled library works and 64-bit compiled library says that it is not a valid application, which is expected.

Would anyone happen to know where is the issue? Do 64-bit DLLs have to be named differently? Is this maybe something to do with the path from which Python looks for the modules? As I said, the DLL and .py are in the same folder.

EDIT: The 32-bit Python was version 3.8, the 64-bit is 3.6. I am running on Windows 10 (64bit)